# Pass non-static class member callback function to ros::subscriber

Tags: c++, arduino, callback, ros, non-static

I'm trying to write a class that handles motor control stuff for a ROS-based robot (specifically for an ESP32 chip using the Arduino IDE).

For this I want to implement a ROS-serial subscriber, that calls a callback function whenever a new message is received. The callback function stores the message data in an instance variable of the class, so I can easily work with it with other functions of the class.

This makes the callback function non static, therefore I used `std::bind` to bind it to the specific instance of my class while keeping a placeholder for the message.

A simplified code example:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

const char cmd_vel_topic[] = "/cmd_vel"

class MotorControlInterface {

  public:
    // FreeRTOS task to call from main
    void TaskMotorControl(void *pvParameters)
    {    
      ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist> twist_sub
      ( 
          // The topic to subscribe to
          cmd_vel_topic,
          // Reference to callback function that is bound to this instance of the class
          &std::bind(&MotorControlInterface::twistCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1),             
      );
      nh.subscribe(twist_sub);
      
      for(;;)
      {
        // Do some stuff with velocity commands
        handleMotorSpeeds();
        vTaskDelay( 10 );
      }
    };

  private:
    // Instance variable I want to store message data in
    double vel_cmd_x;

    // Callback function 
    void twistCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist& twist_msg)
    {
      // Save velocity command
      vel_cmd_x = twist_msg.linear.x;
    };

};
```

The error message I get:

```
Arduino: 1.8.15 (Linux), Board: "ESP32 Dev Module, Disabled, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, None"


/home/ubuntu/Arduino/***/*****.ino: In member function 'void MotorControlInterface::TaskMotorControl(void*)':
*****:83:87: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
         &std::bind( &MotorControlInterface::twistCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1)
                                                                                       ^
*****:84:7: error: no matching function for call to 'ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist>::Subscriber(const char [9], std::_Bind_helper<false, void (MotorControlInterface::*)(const geometry_msgs::Twist&), MotorControlInterface*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type*)'
       );
       ^
In file included from /home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h:60:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Arduino/*****/*****.ino:28:
/home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros/subscriber.h:107:3: note: candidate: ros::Subscriber<MsgT, void>::Subscriber(const char*, ros::Subscriber<MsgT, void>::CallbackT, int) [with MsgT = geometry_msgs::Twist; ros::Subscriber<MsgT, void>::CallbackT = void (*)(const geometry_msgs::Twist&)]
   Subscriber(const char * topic_name, CallbackT cb, int endpoint = rosserial_msgs::TopicInfo::ID_SUBSCRIBER) :
   ^
/home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros/subscriber.h:107:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (MotorControlInterface::*)(const geometry_msgs::Twist&), MotorControlInterface*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type* {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (MotorControlInterface::*)(const geometry_msgs::Twist&)>(MotorControlInterface*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>*}' to 'ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist>::CallbackT {aka void (*)(const geometry_msgs::Twist&)}'
/home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros/subscriber.h:101:7: note: candidate: constexpr ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist>::Subscriber(const ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist>&)
 class Subscriber<MsgT, void>: public Subscriber_
       ^
/home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros/subscriber.h:101:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros/subscriber.h:101:7: note: candidate: constexpr ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist>::Subscriber(ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist>&&)
/home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros/subscriber.h:101:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided

exit status 1
taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

It seems to me like `std::bind` of the callback function does not return what I expect it to, therefore the reference fails. According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) though, the return value is a function object.

As this is my first C/C++ project in a while, I am thankful for any advice on how to get this working. I have spent quite a few hours on this and am not really sure how to continue as the error message doesn't really help me.

**SOLUTION:**
[This solution](https://answers.ros.org/question/258249/publisher-or-subscriber-inside-a-class-rosserial/) works:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

const char cmd_vel_topic[] = "/cmd_vel"

class MotorControlInterface {

  public:
    MotorControlInterface() 
    : twistSubscriber(cmd_vel_topic, &MotorControlInterface::twistCallback, this)
    {
      ; // Stuff to do in the constructor
    };

    // FreeRTOS task to call from main
    void TaskMotorControl(void *pvParameters)
    {    
      nh.subscribe(twist_sub);

      for(;;)
      {
        // Do some stuff with velocity commands
        handleMotorSpeeds();
        vTaskDelay( 10 );
      }
    };

  private:
    // Instance variable I want to store message data in
    double vel_cmd_x;
    ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist, MotorControlInterface> twistSubscriber;

    // Callback function 
    void twistCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist& twist_msg)
    {
      // Save velocity command
      vel_cmd_x = twist_msg.linear.x;
    };

};
```

Comment: It's not so much a matter of what it returns being wrong as the lifetime. The object goes out of scope almost instantly if you don't store it somewhere, and once it's out of scope, the pointer to it is useless.

Comment: I tried storing the return value of `std::bind` into a class variable like this: `std::function<void(geometry_msgs::Twist)> selfTwistCB = std::bind( &MotorControlInterface::twistCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1 );`.
When I use a reference to this class variable, I am greeted with this error: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GxrF9SKr). Apparently I did not choose the correct data type for the variable?

Comment: I have the same issue and your solution doesn't work for me on Arduino because compiler don't understand syntax `ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist, MotorControlInterface> twistSubscriber;` - Error: too many arguments for class template "ros::Subscriber". How did you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

- For **ROS** there is no need to use `std::bind` in combination with the `ros::Subscriber` constructor: For **non-static member functions** [`ros::NodeHandle::subscribe`](http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html) actually has a corresponding overload (where `nh` is your node handle)

  ```
  ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist> twist_sub = nh.subscribe(cmd_vel_topic, 1, &MotorControlInterface::twistCallback, this);
  ```
- For [**`rosserial`**](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) the syntax is slightly different (see [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/noetic-devel/rosserial_client/src/ros_lib/ros/subscriber.h))

  ```
  ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist> twist_sub {cmd_vel_topic, &MotorControlInterface::twistCallback, this};
  nh.subscribe(twist_sub);
  ```

  Further - unlike for ROS - there is no overload for a `boost::function` which means that you won't be able to use your syntax with `boost::bind` or `std::bind` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

When I try your solution, I get this error: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HdG66bKJ)

When checking `ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h`, the compiler is indeed correct and it does not contain the overloaded constructor. 

I created `ros_lib` following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup) and to be save just went through the process again. Is there perhaps a flag I have to set during creation of the lib?

Comment: @Finn2708 Oh, you are on an Arduino with `rosserial`. I have no Arduino at hand but there you should be able to use `ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist> twist_sub {cmd_vel_topic, &MotorControlInterface::twistCallback, this};` in combination with `nh.subscribe(twist_sub);`. Let me know if that works!

Comment: I got it to work meanwhile. I have linked the ressource I used in the original question. Your suggested solution sadly does not work for me ([Error message](https://pastebin.com/2PPQQLab). To me it seems like the type of `&MotorControlInterface::twistCallback` does not match the expected type.